# Bestseller page filtration without on sale products (special price) - magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have bestseller page that load collection of best selled products. I want to remove all on sale products from this page. 
This part of code I have:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
$collection->addIdFilter($productIds)
           ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
           ->addMinimalPrice()
           ->addFinalPrice();
$this->_productCollection = $collection;
$this->_productCollection->load();
```

and I added `->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('null' => true))`
 but its not working:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
$collection->addIdFilter($productIds)
           ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
           ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('null' => true))
           ->addMinimalPrice()
           ->addFinalPrice();
$this->_productCollection = $collection;
$this->_productCollection->load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my

I checked my example and it's works
I had special price instide  of special_price in my file